# Slick Slider go to nth slider on start

Tags: javascript, slider

I want to use Slick Slider to start form 20th slide. My code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.timeline-items').slick({
   slidesToShow: 5,
   slidesToScroll: 4,
   dots:true,
   arrows:true,
   infinite:false,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 4500
});
$('.timeline-items').slickGoTo(20, false);
});
</script>
```

Slider fires OK (.slick functions starts), but then i got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slickGoTo is not a function
```

What I do wrong?

---

from documentation:

```
slickGoTo
int : slide number, boolean: dont animate 
Navigates to a slide by index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          $(function() {

                var tiSlick = $('.timeline-items').slick({
                              slidesToShow: 5,
                              slidesToScroll: 4,
                              dots:true,
                              arrows:true,
                              infinite:false,
                              autoplay: true,
                              autoplaySpeed: 4500
             });
             tiSlick.on('init', function(event, slick) {
             tiSlick.slick('slickGoTo', 20);
        });
    });
```