# Slick slider slickGoTo on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to scroll to a specific slide as soon as the document is ready, but I can only do this when I click on a button. Some idea?

I tried this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176733/slick-slider-go-to-nth-slider-on-start) and nothing

I would prefer to do this without using the slick's init method, if there's a way

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/amLey414/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
<button>
go to 4th
</button>
```

**JS** jquery and slick

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#slide').slick({
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      variableWidth: true,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      infinite: false,
      swipeToSlide: true
   });

  //$(document).ready(function(){
  //    $('#slide').slickGoTo(3);
  //});
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#slide').slick('slickGoTo', 3, false);
  });
  $('#slide').on('init', function(event, slick){
    $('#slide').slick('slickGoTo', 3, false);
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#slide{
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.item{
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I added a class to my last edited item and in Javascript I prepend it to become the first item

```
var $lastEdited = $(".slide-form .last-edited");
$lastEdited.closest('.slide-form').prepend($lastEdited);
```

It's impotant to know that this code needs to be set before the code tha initialize the slide or you'll need to destroy the slide and initialize it again

Answer (score 0):

First, change the speed of Slick option to 0. 
Second, write code.

```
 $('#slide').slick('slickGoTo', 3);
```

Third, change the original speed value.

```
$("#slide").slick('slickSetOption', {
   speed : 400
});
```